# While compling after adding pthon.h header file the following error is occuring: fatal error: python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cython, fedora

I have installed cython and the python-devel package. Still facing the same issue. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you post more detail about your error?

Comment: Specifically how you are calling the compiler? If you do it through setup.py it should set the include path automatically. Otherwise you may have to give the path yourself

Comment: Probably a missing `python3-devel` . ..... `# dnf install python3-devel python3-Cython` ......    ( The old Python 2.7 had end of life January 1, 2020.)